# Recursion - Double each char of a string input and cut of the last char afterwards with one method

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following *problem*.

The ***recursive*** method `public static String doSomeMagic("Test")` should return:

```
TTeesstt
TTeess
TTee
TT
```

I've implemented this behaviour already like this:

```
public static String rowFunction(String s) {
    String toReturn = new String();

    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        toReturn = String.valueOf(s.charAt(0));
        toReturn += toReturn + rowFunction(s.substring(1));
    }
    return toReturn;
}

public static String doSomeMagic(String s) {
    String toReturn = new String();

    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        toReturn = rowFunction(s) + "\n" + doSomeMagic(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

How can one achieve this with just one function?